# How can I get a reliable timeout on a blocked/slow database operation in C# with Dapper, since commandTimeout is not robust enough?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, dapper, .net-5

SQL Server's .NET Client in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient gives us an IDbConnection that supports operations, many of which have a `commandTimeout parameter`.  However, I learned that `commandTimeout` is applied at a lower level and [does not guarantee or even always try to timeout if the whole operation exceeds that time](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/927). (I'm using Dapper's `QueryAsync`, but I think any database access approach would encounter the same problem.)

So how do I set things up so that I can time out or otherwise throw an exception?  I tried [creating a WithTimeout extension method](https://gist.github.com/szalapski/f46e4ea2215e4f7e4b454623af27d86d) based on `await`ing a Delay, but that also isn't guaranteed to fire in a timely fashion.  My code now has seemingly random hangs (probably due to blocking locks) which I could easily handle if they threw an exception, but currently it seems that there is no way to force the database `QueryAsync` operation.  How can I get a real timeout on a blocked/slow database operation in C# using Dapper?

It appears that Dapper doesn't support cancellation tokens.**Is there some broader approach to querying the database that could guarantee either completion or an error in a certain time**, say 20 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some broader approach to querying the database that could guarantee either completion or an error in a certain time, say 20 seconds?

Yes, there is. There is a broader approach to performing asynchronous IO that guarantees completion or error in a specified time.

In C#, one can create `CancellationToken`s that are cancelled after a given time span. Most `async` methods accept a `CancellationToken`. `IDbConnection.QueryAsync` is no exception.

You create a cancellation token source, which takes an optional argument specifying the delay before the task is cancelled (as a `TimeSpan` or `int`

See example:

```cs
try
{
  IDbConnection db = ...;
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10_000);
  var cmd = new CommandDefinition(commandText: "your query", cancellationToken: cts.Token);
  await db.QueryAsync<Foo>(cmd);
  // Success.
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e)
{
// Failure due to timeout.
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a Dapper question after all.  I was under the impression Dapper didn't support cancellation tokens.  I have edited the question; thanks, and I'll try it out soon.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering what 10_000 is, the underscore is a thousands separator introduced C# 7.0. You can put it anywhere you like in an integer constant, except first and last.